# Installing multiple mongoDB versions on the same server

Tags: linux, redhat, installation, mongodb

I have installed a 2.4 mongoDB version and I'd like to compare against the recently released 2.6 version.

I want to know if possible to do a clean new install rather en an update to see if those two version can co-exist in the same server.

I'm using Linux red-hat distro at this moment.

thanks.

Comment: Compile a newer version, use a different install path. If you want to run them at the same time (bad idea) use different ports.

Comment: Here are the instructions:  http://www.mongodb.org/about/tutorial/build-mongodb-on-linux/

Comment: Alternately you can install a second version with the tar/gzipped binaries rather than using a package manager. They are available here: http://www.mongodb.org/dl/linux/x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`mlaunch` tool](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mlaunch) by [Thomas Rueckstiess](http://www.rueckstiess.net/).  Once you download different versions of the binaries from the [download page](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) as suggested in the comments (and put them somewhere that makes sense on your system) you can then use `mlaunch` to start identical configurations for testing by specifying a different [binary path](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mlaunch#binary-path) (and [data directory](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mlaunch#data-directory), [port](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mlaunch#start-port) etc. if running multiple in parallel).

If extra tools are not what you are looking for you can achieve similar results using the internal test commands provided by MongoDB, though please note **that these commands are currently considered internal for testing purposes, are not documented, and can be changed (or stop working) at any time** (I have tested recently on 2.4 and 2.6 versions and can confirm that they work for those versions as of writing this answer).

For example, if you want to set up a 2 shard cluster, where each shard was a replica set, you could do the following:

```
// start a shell from the command line, do not connect to a database
./mongo --nodb
// using that shell start a new 2 shard cluster (this will take a while)
cluster = new ShardingTest({shards : 2, rs : true});
// once that is finished, start a new shell and connect to the mongos (leave previous shell running to monitor logs etc.)
./mongo --port 30999
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:30999/test
mongos>
```

Repeat and re-use as needed with whatever version you wish, to shut it down, simply [`Ctrl-C`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C) the original shell (where things are hopefully still logging).

Similarly, if you just want a replica set to test with:

```
// start a shell from the command line, do not connect to a database
./mongo --nodb
var rst = new ReplSetTest({ name: 'testSet', nodes: 3});
rst.startSet();
// this next line can be hard to type with logging scrolling by, so copy & paste is your friend if you have trouble
rst.initiate();
// start a new shell and connect to the set
 ./mongo --port 31000
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:31000/test
testSet:PRIMARY>
```

Answer (score 1):

These commands can be used to download mongodb rpm and extract the files. After extracting package contents, binary files can be used directly.

```
yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp mongodb-org-server
mkdir /usr/local/mongo2
cd /usr/local/mongo2
rpm2cpio /tmp/mongodb-org-server-2.6.4-1.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

Now, new `mongod` can be invoked with:

```
/usr/local/mongo2/usr/bin/mongod
```