# glibc-2.14 conflicts with file from package glibc2.12

Tags: redhat, mongodb, rhel7, glibc

Mongo V2.6 is already installed on my server which is probably using glibc-2.12.  When I try to install Mongo V3.0.12 it is trying to install glibc-2.14 which it cannot do.

How can I have both glibc libraries live on my RedHat Version 7 64 bit server?

Here is what is currently installed and running:

```
#-> rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-headers-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64
glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64

#-> mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
```

Here are the errors I am getting when trying to install mongo V3.0.12:

```
yum install -y mongodb-org-3.0.12 
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, jnj-amazon, rhui-lb, security
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.0.12-1.el7.x86_64 (MongoDB)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.0.12-1.el7.x86_64 (MongoDB)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.0.12-1.el7.x86_64 (MongoDB)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.0.12-1.el7.x86_64 (MongoDB)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So I got the RPM I need but it won't install:

```
#-> rpm -i glibc-2.14.1-14.12.5.x86_64.rpm
warning: glibc-2.14.1-14.12.5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature,
    key ID 3dbdc284: NOKEY
    file /usr/share/man/man1/localedef.1.gz from install of 
        glibc-2.14.1-14.12.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package 
        man-pages-3.22-20.el6.noarch
    file /etc/gai.conf from install of glibc-2.14.1-14.12.5.x86_64 
        conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64
    file /etc/ld.so.conf from install of glibc-2.14.1-14.12.5.x86_64
        conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64
    file /etc/nsswitch.conf from install of glibc-2.14.1-14.12.5.x86_64 
        conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: This isn't a RHEL 7 server.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but I don't think the RHEL release matters.



    cat /etc/redhat-release 
    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Comment: Of course it matters. And trying to install packages that aren't even for RHEL is a great way to break your system, too. Which is why you weren't allowed to do it.

Comment: So would my best bet be to use a RHEL7 server and install both mongo V3.0.12 and mongo V2.6?

Answer (score 0):

After doing much googling and reading the glibc library seems to be too difficult to replace.  My server that I was originally going to use was running RHEL6.6 Santiago which has glibcV12.

Instead I spun up a new RHEL7.2 server which has glibcV17.  (In my readings I learned that glibc is backwards compatible meaning yes ... I can install both Mongo DBV2.6.7 and MongoDB V3.0!!!)

First I followed the directions to install MongoDB V2.6.7 from any number of websites.  This mongod executable will be the default and live in the /usr/bin directory.

Second I followed the directions listed here to install MongoDB V3.0:
[Installing multiple mongoDB versions on the same server](https://serverfault.com/questions/590576/installing-multiple-mongodb-versions-on-the-same-server)